# Using ProgressBar with AsyncTask for sending SMS | Android

Tags: android, sms, progress-bar

I want an `AsyncTask` to send an SMS given the parameters. The SMS is being sent correctly, but I want to show a `ProgressBar` until the SMS is sent and then take the user to a new activity. I looked on the internet for examples, but I could not figure out what I want to do with my case. Below is my `AsyncTask`

```
public class sendSms extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{            

         protected void onPreExecute() {
             pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //pb is the ProgressBar   
            }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
             SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
             sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);       
            return null;                
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
             //Not sure what to do here
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(){
            Intent intn = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intn);
        }           
}
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer to your question BUT...you can't use `this` as the first parameter of the `Intent` in your `onPostExecute(...)` method. Using `this` actually refers to the `AsyncTask` itself which doesn't extend `Context`. If the `AsyncTask` is defined as an inner class of `SomeActivity` then use `SomeActivity.this`.

Comment: @Squonk: yes, the question is modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check the source code.

```
public class sendSms extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>{            

         protected void onPreExecute() {
             pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //pb is the ProgressBar   
            }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
             SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
             sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);       
            return "Done";                
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
             //Not sure what to do here
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
if(result.equals("Done"))
        {
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Intent intn = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intn);
}
    }
```

}

I think it help you.

Thanks

Comment: how you can add `String` parameter into `onPostExecute` method when third generic param is `Void`?